# Couchdb filtering results using reduce function and startkey/endkey

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

I have documents that set up like this:

```
{ _id: 1, name: "A", timestamp: 1478115739, type: "report" }
{ _id: 2, name: "B", timestamp: 1478103721, type: "transmission" }
{ _id: 3, name: "C", timestamp: 1473114714, type: "report" }
```

I am trying to create a view that only returns the documents within a specific timestamp range. And I would love to be able to filter by type as well.

Here is my javascript call for the the data:

```
db.query('filters/timestamp_type', { startKey: 1378115739, endKey: 1478115740  })
.then(function(resp) {
    //do stuff
})
```

I only know where to put the starting and ending timestamps. I'm having a hard time figuring out where I would say I only want the **report**'s returned.

In addition, this is my map function for my filter, which is obviously not even close to being complete. I'm not sure how I even access the start and end key.

```
function (doc) {
  if(type == "report" && startKey >= doc.timestamp && endKey <= doc.timestamp)
    emit(doc._id, doc.name);
}
```

My question remains:

- Where do I retrieve the start and end key's in my map function?
- How can I add an addition *type* filter for only getting a specific type of report.

I know I might need to use a reduce function but it's going over my head. Here is the default reduce function but I'm not sure how it would work with the map function.

```
function (keys, values, rereduce) {
  if (rereduce) {
    return sum(values);
  } else {
    return values.length;
  }
}
```

Thank you, any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a map function to get reports by a specific type-

```
function(doc) {
   if(doc.type == "report") {
     emit(doc.timestamp, doc);
   }
}
```

when the view is queried, only documents with the type 'report' will be returned. If you need to support multiple types, you will have to create a new view for each type.

To query this view and specify the start & end timestamps, just add them to your query-

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:5984/<your-database>/_design/docs/_view/<your-view-name>?startkey="1478115739"&endkey="1478103721"
```

[Reference](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html])

Comment: How does the start key and end key know to look at the timestamp field? There is no way to make one view to work with any type based on my query?

Comment: Your view will emit only the timestamp field. So the startkey,endkey and key parameter will work only on the emitted key : timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @AlexisCôté So if I have 50 types, I have to make 50 views? There is no way to sort by both timestamp start/end and by type in a single view?

Comment: @bryan You can emit multiple keys  as an array and then, you query your view using complex keys. Take a look at [this](http://ryankirkman.com/2011/03/30/advanced-filtering-with-couchdb-views.html) or lookup for "complex keys" on google and you will find plenty of information. Another alternative is to use the new CouchDB Mango Query (Available for 2.0 only).

Comment: @AlexisCôté I'm having a real hard time finding anywhere that actual explains the process with the actual map/reduce function. Everywhere I go people just show the really confusing query with no explanation.

Comment: @bryan Take a look at my [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/couchdb/7007/views#t=20161103143418667508). If you have any other related questions to the complex queries, you can ask another question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @bryan - here is a sample query (non-complex key) using date ranges for start and endkey-

`GET /my_db/_design/views/_view/find_documents_by_updated_date?startkey=%222016-11-11T15%3A14%3A03.891506Z%22&endkey=%222016-11-11T15%3A14%3A04.024320Z%22&limit=2 200
` The start and end key values are ISO formatted date strings.Note - you have to encode the quotes for this to work.